# List elements matching collection of constraints using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity defined like this in PostgreSQL (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5a2ec/1):

```sql
create table foo (
  id bigint primary key,
  code varchar(4) not null,
  label varchar(255) not null,
  from_date date not null,
  to_date date null,
  unique (code, from_date)
);
```

I can get the most advanced elements (with max `from_date`) matching a collection of `code` using native PostgreSQL query...

```sql
select f1.* 
from 
  foo f1,
  (select code, max(from_date) max_from_date from foo where code in ('a', 'b', 'c') group by code) f2
where f1.code = f2.code and f1.from_date = f2.max_from_date;
```

...but I'm not able to create a similar query using CriteriaQuery or JPQL.

My problem is I understood subqueries can only be used in  ̀where`clause and cannot use`multiselect`.

Comment: why wouldn't "select foo from Foo foo where foo.fromDate in (select max(f2.fromDate) from foo f2 where code in ('a', 'b', 'c') group by code) and foo.code in  ('a', 'b', 'c')" work?

Comment: I think your query does not guarantee the uniqueness of `code` in the results set.